# can not use cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan, warden

I am following rails casts episode 192 for cancan (http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan?autoplay=true).

I have ruby 1.9.3
and rails 3.2.3

My gem file has this content

```
group :test, :development do
   gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.5'
end
group :test do 
   gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.0.6'# use this instead of the one in the book
   gem 'capybara'
   gem 'database_cleaner'
end

gem 'dynamic_form'
gem 'factory_girl'
gem 'devise', '~>1.4.3'
gem 'email_spec'
gem 'cancan'
```

and in the environment.rb file I have added

```
config.gem 'cancan'
```

when I run bundle command I see this...

```
Using warden (1.0.6) 
Using devise (1.4.9) 
Using dynamic_form (1.1.4) 
Using rspec-core (2.11.0) 
Using rspec-expectations (2.11.1) 
Using rspec-mocks (2.11.0) 
Using rspec (2.11.0)
```

Now my question is: when I run:

```
sudo rake gems:install
```

then why do I see this:

```
Could not find warden-1.0.6 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

and also in my gem.lock file why does it show...

```
devise (1.4.9)
  bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
  orm_adapter (~> 0.0.3)
  warden (~> 1.0.3)
```

Comment: How is your Ruby installed? After running bundle install, why are you doing sudo rake gems:install?

Comment: I used rvm to install ruby. I am doing the sudo rake gems:install because it is there in the episode. But when I do that then it tells me that I need to run the bundle install first because the gem warden, 1.0.6 is missing and cancan needs that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That railscast is from Dec 14, 2009 back when Rails 2 was the standard.

You should go through the instructions at https://github.com/ryanb/cancan which focus more on Rails 3 and Bundler.

`bundle install` will install your Gemfile contents into your current RVM gemset, in this case, probably the default gemset. Do NOT use sudo to install gems. To list the gems installed in the gemset, just run `gem list`. Run `bundle list` to show all of the gems in the current application bundle.